# Plotting dataframes separately from dictionary of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a for loop that makes separate plots for all dataframes from a dictionary of dataframes. I am not trying to make a subplot.

I have a dictionary named roi_exon_dict.
In this dictionary, there are 15 separate dataframes that ALL share the same indexes, number of rows, and column labels. The dictionary is in Key: Value format, where every key is a dataframe.

My dictionary looks something like this:

```
key    Type         Size         Value 

V1C    DataFrame   (17,10)   Column names : 'early_prenatal', 'mid_prenatal', 'late_prenatal', 'early_childhood', 'childhood', 'late_childhood', 'early_adolescent', 'late_adolescent', 'early_adulthood', 'late_adulthood'
A1C    DataFrame   (17,10)   Column names : 'early_prenatal', 'mid_prenatal', 'late_prenatal', 'early_childhood', 'childhood', 'late_childhood', 'early_adolescent', 'late_adolescent', 'early_adulthood', 'late_adulthood'
.
.
.
VFC    DataFrame   (17,10)   Column names : 'early_prenatal', 'mid_prenatal', 'late_prenatal', 'early_childhood', 'childhood', 'late_childhood', 'early_adolescent', 'late_adolescent', 'early_adulthood', 'late_adulthood'
```

Every dataframe in this dictionary looks like this:

```
index    early_prenatal   mid_prenatal    late_prenatal   ...  early_adulthood
165697      0.6525           0.1332           0.0                    0.0
165698      0.6509           0.1331           0.0                    0.0
.
.
.
165713      0.6490           0.1303           0.0                    0.0
```

How can I create a for loop that iterates through every region of interest (refer to key) in the master dictionary, plotting each region of interest as its own plot? I have tried many suggestions but there are countless errors that keep appearing as I try to implement codes found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678601/how-to-plot-all-dataframes-from-a-dictionary-of-dataframes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816097/attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-plot).

I want my plots to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmD5y.png), where the x-ticks are the age groups, each line is a separate exon (refer to the index in each dataframe), and the y-values are the column values.

I haven't worked with for loops before, so I apologize if this question seems pretty rudimentary. I don't even know if I have the for loop layout right. This is what I have so far:

```
for roi in roi_exon_dict[roi]:
    print("I am now working on this region: " + str(roi) + ".") #displays which region the loops is working on
    ticks = list(range(len(age_groups))) #setting x-ticks, age_group was previously defined as a list 
    roi_exon_dict[roi].plot(figsize=(35,15)) #plotting specific region from dictionary
    plt.xlabel("Age Group", fontsize=18)
    plt.xticks(ticks, age_groups.keys(), rotation=45, fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel("Raw RPKM", fontsize=18)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
    plt.title("x")
    title = (str(gene_name) + ' Expression in ' + str(roi))
    plt.title(str(title), fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
    plt.legend(all_exon_inds, loc=0)
    plt.margins(x=0)
else:
    print("I'm finished graphing these plots.") #do nothing
```

I keep getting an error that says "no numeric data to plot." or "dict object has no attribute." Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your dictionary already have dataframes, you don't need to do `pd.DataFrame( ...`. Just refer to each df as `roi_exon_dict[roi]`.

Comment: All you need is `for next_df in roi_exon_dict.values():` and then `next_df `IS the DataFrame and the columns for plotting are just available using for example `next_df['early_prenatal']` and so on.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Thanks for the feedback. Could you expand on this a bit further? I modified the for loop so that it goes `for roi in roi_exon_dict[roi]` and updated my code above. I now get the error `KeyError: 'early_prenatal'`

Comment: @user19077881 Thanks for the suggestion. I modified my for loop to fit with your suggestion but I only get one graph in return and only for the final dataframe in the dictionary. The graph is completely empty and has no values; the labels and ticks are the only things accurately displayed on the graph. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very minimal example which shows the principles and may be a useful basis. Using `for df in my_dict.values()` would just give the DFs; here I use `.items()` to get the key names to use in the title.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1= pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'y': [ 23, 45, 68, 78, 85]
                   })

df2= pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'y': [ 32, 54, 86, 87, 89]
                   })

my_dict = {'d1': df1, 'd2': df2}

for name, df in my_dict.items():
    plt.title(name)
    plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])
    plt.xlabel('These are x values')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: OP wants to plot everything in one figure, so `plt.show()` should be outside the loop.

Comment: @David It's not clear to me if the OP wants that. To put `plt.show()` outside the loop would require subplots created using `plt.subplot` and the OP seems to be suggesting that subplots are not wanted.

Comment: @user19077881 thanks for the insight. How would I modify the loop to plot more than just one value for x and y? I don't think a scatterplot is what I want for the graph. I'm trying to make a time-series. I want the x values to be the age groups (of which there are 10), and the y-values to be the values found in the columns. Each dataframe is 17 x 10. Ideally every row would correspond to an individual line on the graph. This dataset is mapping gene expression (exon) over time (age groups).

Comment: My code is simply an example of the looping for each DF as I understood your essential difficulty. You can use any sort of plot with any number of y values; you could have an inner loop going through the columns of a DF plotting each then finally using `plt.show()`. I suggest you focus on one DF and get the plot you want working then apply it to all the DFs. If you have difficulties with plotting one example DF then explain what the difficulty is.